# Open a piped URL in Google Chrome in Bash (OSX)

Tags: bash, google-chrome, sed

I'm trying to pass a value (Git's origin URL, manipulated with `sed`) via pipe to Chrome in bash on OSX.  I have tried the following:

I can get the two separate parts working, but when I put them together Chrome does not open the URL as I would expect.

- `git config --get remote.origin.url | sed "s/git@/https:\/\//g"` (outputs `https://github.com/myProject/`)
- `echo 'https://example.com' | /usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"` (correctly opens `https://example.com`)

However, if I stick these two together, Chrome opens but just to a blank page (`about:blank`):

- `git config --get remote.origin.url | sed "s/git@/https:\/\//g" | xargs /usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"`
- or
- `git config --get remote.origin.url | sed "s/git@/https:\/\//g" | /usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine I found that I had to do

```
git config --get remote.origin.url | sed 's/\.git//; s/git@/www\./; s#https://#www\.#; s#\.com:#\.com/#'
```

In order to get the output

```
www.github.com/myProject/
```

This is the URL format that chrome seems to like.

1. I added `'s/\.git//;` to get rid of the `.git` at the end of the URL
2. I added `s/git@/www\./; s#https://#www\.#;` to swap `git@`(For ssh cloned repos) and `https://`(For non-ssh cloned repos) with `www.`
3. I added `s#\.com:#\.com/#` to get rid of the colon ':'

And here is the *whole shebang*

```
git config --get remote.origin.url | sed 's/\.git//; s/git@/www\./; s#https://#www\.#; s#\.com:#\.com/#' | xargs /usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"
```

### UPDATE

A more robust solution:
1. Verify the remote origin URL even exists
2. Updated `sed` script
3. Error statement when script fails

```sh
git config --get remote.origin.url &>/dev/null && git config --get remote.origin.url | sed 's/\.git//; s/git@//; s#https://##; s#:#/#g' | xargs firefox || echo 'Error: no git remote URL
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, I forgot about the `:username` part needing to be altered to a forward slash!